# Ubuntu 18.04 invisible mouse

Tags: 18.04, mouse, mouse-pointer, pointers

I had Ubuntu 16.04 and suddenly I couldn't log in anymore. Each time I would try to log in, the screen went black and ask again for my password. I was stuck in a login loop. I updated to Ubuntu 18.04 and it fixed my problem, but now the mouse cursor is invisible. I can still click things, except I can't see the cursor.

I use Ubuntu with Parallels in my MacOs High Sierra.

Comment: I found this worked for me if someone wants to convert it to a full answer: https://forum.antergos.com/topic/4375/invisible-mouse-cursor-after-sleep-lock/10

Comment: The above comment's solution works for me too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On my system it was due to a broken upgrade,

Open the terminal with  <kbd>crtl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd> and run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` let it run until it stops; and then update with `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` and reboot (`sudo reboot` if you can't use the gui to do that).

My cursor was back again.

[`dpkg` with the `--configure -a` flags](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dpkg.1.html#actions) set will tell `dkpg` to configure any packages that have been unpacked but not configured.

`apt update` checks available repositories for any available upgrades, and `apt upgrade` tells `apt` to upgrade any packages that need it.

Comment: Care to elaborate what version upgrade, and why this command came to the rescue?

Comment: Added an explanation of what each command does. In general, we probably shouldn't encourage readers to run arbitrary sudo commands. I always try to expand on the function of each command, so that people don't get used to the idea that it's safe or reasonable to "just run this" without understanding it.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://web.archive.org/web/20190522173355/https://forum.antergos.com/topic/4375/invisible-mouse-cursor-after-sleep-lock/10) worked for me. I changed "intel" to "amd" because I'm running threadripper cpu. In my case I also had to run:

`sudo mkdir /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` before creating the file.

1. Create the file
   `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-cursoron.conf`
2. Put in it the following content

```
#--makes mouse cursor re-appear
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Device0"
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "AccelMethod" "uxa"
    Option      "SWCursor"    "on"
EndSection
#--
```

The keyword is `uxa accekeration` method here.
`Logout-login`

Comment: This worked for me mid-2023 on Linux Mint 21.2 "victoria", except I used the "amd" driver to match my video card.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (apparently default mode is "touchscreen mode"):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false
```

Comment: This works for me but my situation is a little different: the cursor disappears after I install a new desktop environment (still 16.04).

Comment: This also worked for me. I upgraded my Thinkpad X1 from 18.04 (mouse was fine) to 20.04 and my trackpad/mouse disappeared but the touchscreen was still working. I did have to restart to see this change however.